# In React Native, how can I get the Y offset of a custom component and then scroll a ScrollView to its position?

Tags: javascript, uiscrollview, react-native, scrollview

In React Native, I have a screen with a `ScrollView`:

```
let scrollView;
let myComponent2;

function onPress() {
  myComponent2.measure((frameOffsetX, frameOffsetY, width, height, pageOffsetX, pageOffsetY) => {
  scrollView.scrollTo({ y: frameOffsetY });
}

function MyScrollView() {
  return (
    <ScrollView ref={ref => scrollView = ref}>
      <MyButton onPress={onPress} />
      <MyComponent1 />
      <MyComponent2 ref={ref => myComponent2 = ref} />
      <MyComponent3 />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

And `MyButton` is defined like this:

```
function MyButton(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={props.onPress}>
      <Text>Press Me</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the user presses on the `MyButton` component, the `ScrollView` should scroll so that `MyComponent2` is visible. The problem is that I can't use `measure` on a custom component, only directly in a `View`.

So my question is: **what would be the best approach to get the Y offset of a custom React Native component?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up wrapping my component around an extra `View` to be able to get its offset:

```
let scrollView;
let myComponent2Wrapper;

function onPress() {
  myComponent2Wrapper.measure((frameOffsetX, frameOffsetY, width, height, pageOffsetX, pageOffsetY) => {
  scrollView.scrollTo({ y: frameOffsetY });
}

function MyScrollView() {
  return (
    <ScrollView ref={ref => scrollView = ref}>
      <MyButton onPress={onPress} />
      <MyComponent1 />
      <View ref={ref => myComponent2Wrapper = ref}>
        <MyComponent2 />
      </View>
      <MyComponent3 />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am not getting correct `pageOffsetY` position value for a view which I have added `ref`. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Please [check my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639892/react-native-how-to-get-y-offset-value-of-a-view-from-scrollview) and let me know your suggestion.