# React Native - How to get Y Offset Value of a view from ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, react-native, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am trying to get the scroll position of a view. But the value for **Y offset to page** which is not related to the view's position.

**ScrollView Hierarchy:**

```
<ScrollView>
  - MyComponent1
  - MyComponent2
    - SubView1
       - SubView2
         - <View> (Added ref to this view and passing Y offset value through props)
  - MyComponent3
 </ScrollView>
```

**SubView2 Component:**

```
this.myComponent.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
   console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
   console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
   console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
   console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
   console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
   console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)

   this.props.moveScrollToParticularView(py)
})

<View ref={view => { this.myComponent = view; }}>
```

I have checked the exact position of a `SubView2` view on `onScroll` method. But did match with the `measure value`. I can figure it out the `measure value` is wrong.

Is it ScrollView hierarchy problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`View` component has a property called [`onLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout). You can use this property to get the position of that component.

> **onLayout**
>
> Invoked on mount and layout changes with:
>
> ```
> {nativeEvent: { layout: {x, y, width, height}}}
> ```
>
> This event is fired immediately once the layout has been calculated,
>   but the new layout may not yet be reflected on the screen at the time
>   the event is received, especially if a layout animation is in
>   progress.

**Update**

`onLayout` prop gives a position to the parent component. This means to find the position of `SubView2`, you need to get total of all the parent components (`MyComponent2` + `SubView1` + `SubView2`).

**Sample**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    position: 0,
  };
  _onLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y, width, height } } }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      position: prevState.position + y
    }));
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // This will scroll the view to SubView2
      this.scrollView.scrollTo({x: 0, y: this.state.position, animated: true})
    }, 5000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container} ref={(ref) => this.scrollView = ref}>
        <View style={styles.view}>
          <Text>{'MyComponent1'}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'blue'}]} onLayout={this._onLayout}>
          <Text>{'MyComponent2'}</Text>
          <View style={[styles.view, , { backgroundColor: 'green'}]} onLayout={this._onLayout}>
            <Text>{'SubView1'}</Text>
            <View style={[styles.view, { backgroundColor: 'yellow'}]} onLayout={this._onLayout}>
              <Text>{'SubView2'}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya. Tried with `onLayout` also. Actually `Y value` is 0 for `subview2`. I am getting Y value if I add ref on `MyComponent2`

Comment: ya. I guess need to add on each parent. Let me try with this.