# How to scroll to component onPress with useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

its a simple question, i just dont find the method that can handle this.

1. i declare use ref variable like so:

   ```
    const massageTypeRef = useRef();
   ```
2. Now I have Text component at the top of the page:

   ```
                <Text ref={massageTypeRef} style={styles.massagetitle}>
                Choose type:
            </Text>
   ```

3.and i have another button in the bottom , i want when the button clicked, take the user all the way up to the Text component.
in my bottom button i have:

```
<AnimatedButton
                onPress={() => console.log(massageTypeRef.current}/// here i dont know what i need to 
                 pass
                icon="arrow-up"
                buttonStyle={styles.problembutton}
                textStyle={styles.problembuttontext}
            />
```

i tried:

```
onPress={() =>
                    massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: "smooth",
                    })
```

and:

```
onPress={() =>
                    massageTypeRef.current.scrollTo()
                    })
```

but i always get: TypeError: massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView is not a function. (In 'massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView()', 'massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView' is undefined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In React Native, how can I get the Y offset of a custom component and then scroll a ScrollView to its position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450468/in-react-native-how-can-i-get-the-y-offset-of-a-custom-component-and-then-scrol)

Comment: no ...
i just want to know the function that do that...
and how can i get the place of the text input

Comment: can i scroll to Text component? or i need to wrap it in view?

Comment: You can't scroll, you can translate it.

Comment: ok .. so how?...

Comment: @RoeiGrinshpan Give me a snack url and I'll try to help you.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/OYWlNQwP4

Comment: now i see that its work. i dont know why in my real project is get undefined...

Comment: Where does it work?

Comment: snack.expo.io/OYWlNQwP4 here

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: no. in my project i try to do the same but i get " ref.current.scrollIntoView is not a function.....

Comment: TypeError: massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView is not a function. (In 'massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView()', 'massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView' is undefined)

Comment: if i console.log massageTypeRef.current.scrollIntoView i get undefined.

for example if i console.log  massageTypeRef.current.focus i get [function]

Comment: I got that error in your snack.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/OYWlNQwP4
work perfect..

Comment: @RoeiGrinshpan You sure? It says that ref.current.scrollIntoView() is not a function

Comment: Ok... so wy is this? Maybe i must it on scrollview?